# Item in a collection represented by Items.Count can be the latest or the first to be received

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code which runs on two computers.

```
Option Explicit
Public olApp As Outlook.Application
Public olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Public olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Public olItms As Outlook.Items
Public myItms As Outlook.Items
Public myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
Public olMail As Variant
Public i As Long
Public Sender As Outlook.AddressEntry
Public Number As Long
Public environment As String
Public MyObj As Object
Public MySource As Object
Public file As Variant
Public myFile As Variant
Public textline As Variant
Public Text As Variant
Public identifier As Boolean
Public j As Long
Public k As Long
Public counter As Long

Sub MySub()

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items
Set myDestFolder = olFldr.Folders("Tradebook")
Set myItms = myDestFolder.Items

On Error GoTo ContinueHere2:

counter = olItms.Count
```

On my computer it sees olItms.Count as the latest email in my inbox i.e. Item 20,000 is the latest email received.
On my colleague's computer, it interprets olItms.Count to be the first-ever email to be received.

I need to understand why this happens because if it were to switch without me knowing when and why it could be disastrous.

Comment: Isn't the `.Count` returning the number of items (emails) in the inbox?

Comment: yes it does. I forgot to say I then use the code olItms(counter).Subject to get the subject of the email, which of course from the above would suggest giving different subjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866960(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Items class to sort the collection of items by the specified property. Sort only affects the order of items in a collection. It does not affect the order of items in an explorer view.

```
Sub SortByRecievedDate() 
  Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
  Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
  Dim myItem As Outlook.TaskItem 
  Dim myItems As Outlook.Items 

  Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks) 
  Set myItems = myFolder.Items 
  myItems.Sort "[RecievedTime]", False 
  For Each myItem In myItems 
    MsgBox myItem.Subject & "-- " & myItem.DueDate 
  Next myItem 
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect this has solved the issue and I can now use both codes in tandem. However I would still love to know why this was occuring if anyone has any input???

Comment: The items collection will not be in any particular order unless you explicitly sort it. You should never expect any order unless Sort is called.